# consul proxy socket connection failed

Tags: consul

agent: Check "service:socat-proxy" socket connection failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:20108: connect: connection refused

It works in `-dev` mode but in normal server mode I get the above error? No clue where to start. Everything else seem to be working except proxy?

```
{
  "connect": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "service": {
    "name": "socat",
    "tags": [],
    "port": 8181,
    "connect": {
      "proxy": {
        "config": {
          "bind_address": "127.0.0.1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to explicitly turn on gRPC in normal server mode. In the dev mode, gRPC is enabled by default. Simply add a config of ports and define the gRPC port.